# Create EXE Files From VB.Net Script

Tags: vb.net, file, exe

Is there a way to create .exe files from script using VB.Net? I want to create an installer for multiple .exe files, and I already tried out IExpress, but that doesn't work completely fine and then I can't add a form for selecting a destination filepath, so I want to do it in VB.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `system.codedom.compiler` namespace has all the classes neccessary to compile .net code and write .exe and .dll files.

Comment: Microsoft have a handy guide here https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/304655 "How to programmatically compile code using a c# compiler". The example writes and executes an EXE from within .net. This article referencies its companion piece https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/304654 "How to programmatically compile code using VB.net" which gives the same info for VB.net.

Answer (score 0):

I get the answer here: Add the file to My.Resources and copy it to the specified location with `System.IO.File.Copy(My.Resources.file_to_install.exe, "the/specified/file/location.exe")`.

Comment: Not really 'creating' an EXE file - its just copies an existing one. If it works for you though, that's great.

Comment: I know, but with CodeDom.Compiler I can only make Console Applications with 1 codefile.